# restarting server.js for new command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I make discord bot via node.js on my pc and when I start server.js and add command, the new command not working I need to turn off the server.js and turn on  server.js
How I make a new command without restarting the server.js?

The server.js

```
let Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Hello ${client.user.tag}!`);
});



client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "hi"){
    message.channel.send("hi")

  } else if (message.content === "how are you") {
    message.channel.send("I am fine")
} else if (message.content === "test") {
  message.channel.send("okay")
} else if (message.content === "who made you?") {
  message.channel.send("XX")
}





})
client.login("secret_key");
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by adding a new command? Your code looks not properly formated as well..

Comment: @Daweed I mean when I add to server.js exam. else if (message.content === "test") {
  message.channel.send("ok")
}    and save server.js the command test in discord not working , its working after restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how Node.js works. You can edit your file as you like but unless you restart your server the changes won't show up.

For this I recommend you [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), which restarts your server every time file changes in the directory are detected.